# Getting error in production, not in dev or QA - Could not load file or assembly 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml, Version=2.7.2.0

Tags: c#, .net, openxml-sdk

Have an web application that calls a WebService backend. Everything was worked as expected. Not sure exactly when it started but now in production we are getting this error:

*2019-10-22 14:27:05,841 [193] ERROR VplApiService.Controllers.BillingController - Uh oh, something happened!. We are unable to process this LTL Invoice file from file VantagePointShipmentDetailReport.xlsx
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml, Version=2.7.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fb06cb64d019a17' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
File name: 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml, Version=2.7.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fb06cb64d019a17'
   at VPLServices.Shipments.ShipmentService.ProcessEDISupplementalData(String fileName, Byte[] fileData)
   at VplApiService.Controllers.ShipmentsController.d__18.MoveNext()*

Running the code base locally, I am not getting the error, everything is working well.

Pointing to our QA environment, I am also not getting the error, even though I just re-deployed the exact same code as what is in production.

My suspicion is that someone manually messed with a DLL or something on prod. But, how can I tell what DLL? And, more importantly, how can I fix this?

Thank You,
Sammer

Comment: The best way to avoid this sort of issue is to make sure that all your dependencies are deployed with your application to the same folder and you don't rely on the runtime finding them elsewhere. The option is "copy always" in properties for the references.

Comment: Supplementing iakobski's comment: `DocumentFormat.OpenXML` is not a part of the core .NET Framework. It needs to be obtained / installed explicitly (but is free-of-charge and a Microsoft .NET dll). That's why it may be in some environments, but not others.